# Align deployed applet using jnlp

Tags: java, html, applet

I'm trying to align a deployed applet using jnlp.  It defaults to upper left on the web page.  I've tried to set the alignment to *middle* via the java script code that deploys the applet and via the jnlp source.  In either case, the alignment is ignored, or the applet is not displayed. In both cases, I tried passing `align:middle`.  Does anyone know the correct way to set the alignment within the jnlp deployment framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ..set the alignment within the jnlp deployment framework?

That is not the place to do it.  Do in HTML/CSS.

Comment: How can that be done when the applet is deployed dynamically via [deployJava](http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt)?

Comment: The same way you'd do it if the applet was deployed using a plain `applet` element.  Just put the script that embeds the applet, in the same place you would put the `applet`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I was able to center the applet by using the <center> tag around the deployJava script code.